# How can i convert whole column of date in milliseconds to some standard format in java?

Tags: java

I have some data in JSON format and i am representing that in a table. One column is of date and its represented in milliseconds. I am able to convert single value but i cant convert whole column. How can i do that?

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;`

public class Application {
    String myMilliSeconds[] = {"1500156875588L", "1500156875548L", "1500134875588L", "1500156835588L"};

    public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy");
        for(int i=0; i<myMilliSeconds.length; i++) {
        Date resultDate = new Date();
        System.out.println(sdf.format(resultDate));
        }

    }
}
```

In above code i got this error: Error: Main method is not static in class date_time.Application, please define the main method as:

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
```

but when i set method as static then i cant use myMilliSeconds variable.

Comment: you cannot run a class without a public static void main :)

Comment: add static for all

Comment: This question has nothing to do with dates, but to do with basic Java syntax. You need to learn about `static` variables and methods and that `static` actually means.

Comment: What means `cant convert whole column`?

Comment: Or put the array into the main ;)

Comment: Change `String myMilliSeconds[] ` to `static String myMilliSeconds[]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your main method as static (public static void main) and to access "String myMilliSeconds" you need to declare that also "static String myMilliSeconds" as you cannot access that in static method.

## Your program should be something like this

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Application {
    static String  myMilliSeconds[] = {"1500156875588L", "1500156875548L", "1500134875588L", "1500156835588L"};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy");
        for(int i=0; i<myMilliSeconds.length; i++) {
        Date resultDate = new Date();
        System.out.println(sdf.format(resultDate));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I added static before String but now i am getting this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at date_time.Application.main

Comment: Have you used date_time some where? Could you attach the complete code again?

Answer (score 0):

use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-long-) constructor: `Date resultDate = new Date(myMilliSeconds[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

Main method should generally be static because they can then be invoked by the runtime engine without having to instantiate an instance of the parent class.,  If you want you to use the class variables then instantiate the class and then use its properties and variables or declare it static as mentioned in one of the above answers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Application app=new Application();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy");
    for(int i=0; i<app.myMilliSeconds.length; i++) {
    Date resultDate = new Date();
    System.out.println(sdf.format(resultDate));
    }

}
```